# How can i work with nav and main-nav in css

Tags: html, css, class

IN HTML

```
<nav class="nav main-nav">
</nav>
```

IN CSS

```
main-nav li{
    Padding:0 5%
}
```

I am having some trouble here  as i just started learning html , in css main-nav is not giving me response while nav is giving me proper response , is there another attribute that i should write in this

Comment: You question is completely unclear.. please read [ask] and [mcve]. In css you can use for example .main-nav li{}

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add some styles to an element with a specific class, then you should use "." before the selector in CSS (`.nav`)

The case with the `nav` selector works because it's a selector by the tag name (`<nav></nav>`).

So the correct selector for your example would be `.main-nav li`

Answer (score 0):

```css
.main-nav{
  Padding: 0 5%;
}
```

```html
<nav class="main-nav">Use Period (.) with classes. </nav>
```

Use Period (.) with class.

Answer (score 0):

Styles added in nav is only working because it shares the same name with the tag you are using. There are several CSS selectors that are used to target the
HTML elements like classes, id, attribute and tag names. They all have have different targeting method given below

```
.class_name{
  /* used with period sign (.) followed by class name */
}
#id_name{
/* used with pound sign (#)  followed by id name */
}

[alt="apple"]{
  /* used inside brackets*/
}

nav{
  /* styling the element by directly calling element */
}
```

Note: either use camel case or lower case do not use uppercase or capitalize.

To learn more about the basic check the link below

https://www.admecindia.co.in/web-design/top-most-important-things-to-learn-in-html-and-css-for-beginners/